# What is the value of $x$ when $a b^x$ > $ c d^x$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation

I am trying to find the **min** value of *x*, which make that inequality true 
$a b^x$ > $ c d^x$.

And is there any cheat sheet that contains all the formulas to solve those type of inequality and equations?

Comment: I thought that cheat sheets were stuff people made for themselves or for their colleagues. Though the idea of putting a couple of wrong ones online has always enticed me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rearrange the equation (assuming $a,b,c,d>0$) into

$$\left(\frac bd\right)^x > \frac ca$$ which is easier to solve (**hint**: the exponential function is always monotone!)

Comment: why can you assume they are all > 0?

Comment: then let's assume $1.5 ^x$ > $1.75$ then $x$ = 2, but I still don't know how to find it directly.

Comment: @Cato Well, we can assume that $b$ and $c$ are positive since otherwise, the term $b^x$ and $d^x$ aren't defined. And if the signs of $a,c$ are different, then the inequality is either always or never true. Therefore, I assume that $a,b,c,d>0$ in the original question.

Comment: @BasmaAshour Have you heard of logarithms?